# How to group facets (Facet API) by day for date fields?

Tags: search

How to group facets (Facet API) by day for date fields?

Currently I have a custom date field indexed by Search API Solr.

[image]

I want to group this values by day, for example:

> Friday 26 june
>
> -08:30
>
> -08:45
>
> Saturday 27 june
>
> -08:30
>
> Sunday 28 june
>
> -08:30

Answer (score -1):

Use the [numeric_groups](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ianmthomasuk/1734726) module. It is a sandbox project.